How to add or substract current date - exclude SATURDAY and SUNDAY | Oracle
I have been trying to define a logic but not getting.
I just need to - or + the days to my current date
Example :
If my date is  2024-04-15   then -1  -> it should give me ->  2024-04-12
If you see -1 should give me 2024-04-14 -> if falls under saturday and sunday that should be excluded.
If my date is 2024-04-13   then 0  -> it should give me 2024-04-12 ( Friday )
2024-04-13 falls as SATURDAY -> give me output :  2024-04-12 ( Friday )
This following query does not work
select current_date - 1 from dual;

I just given a specific date
In real it should be current_date or sysdate
Expected output:
select to_date(current_date,'YYYY-MM-DD') - 0 from dual 
o/p :  2024-10-12 -> 2024-10-11
 
select to_date(current_date,'YYYY-MM-DD') - 1 from dual 
o/p :  2024-04-15 -> 2024-10-12


what datatype are you using? date or timestamp? Please give examples of your SQL or PL/SQL.

to_date(sysdate,'YYTT-MM-DD')  or current_date

I am using dual no data type

sysdate returns a date datatype. systimestamp returns a timestamp datatype. if you're working with data in a table, the datatype of the column you are selecting is relevant. The name of the table (or "dual" in your case) is not relevant. The math and SQL syntax to achieve what you want is different depending on the datatype you are working with.

please post the SQL and the output you are getting and any error messages.

I have added what is am expecting as o/p ( output )

In simple way the solution is
SELECT CASE to_char(current_date+5,'DY') WHEN 'SAT' THEN Current_date+7
WHEN 'SUN' THEN current_date+6
ELSE CURRENT_DATE+5 END  FROM DUAL;
